# Why are handshake and master secrets distinct in TLS?

Tags: tls

In [TLS 1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446.html#page-93), handshake messages (except for ClientHello and ServerHello) are protected by keys derived from the *handshake secret*. After the handshake completes, *master secret* is derived from the handshake secret, which is then used to derive keying material for application messages.

Why are handshake and master secrets distinct? What security issues would arise if the handshake secret was used as the first master secret instead?

Comment: The master is about I know you, the rest is about forward secrecy.